# Speed up Google script value access and metadata?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a number of functions that look at cell values and use them to set other cell values or developer metadata, as well as look at the metadata to decide what to do. As I was stress testing the functionality of my spreadsheet I ran into problems when running a script for a big range of cells would exceed the [maximum runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).
Looking into it, I noticed that getting and setting cell values, of a predefined cell, takes about 0.2 seconds, and finding and setting metadata takes about 0.5 - 0.8 seconds.
I wrote an example script to show this but for some reason the times are shorter in that, i don't know if that has to do with what is in the cell or that the spreadsheet is smaller or ....
However changing a value in a sheet that already has some metadata for the specified key and triggering this script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  timetest(e)
}

function timetest(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  for (var r = 1; r <= range.getNumRows(); r++){
    for (var c = 1; c <= range.getNumColumns(); c++){
      var cell = range.getCell(r, c);
      var value = cell.getValue();
      var new_val = value + ' ' + r + c;
      cell.setValue(new_val);
    }
    var metadata = sheet.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey("Updated").find()
    if (metadata.length > 0){
      metadata[0].setValue(new_val)
    } else {
      sheet.addDeveloperMetadata("Updated", new_val, SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataVisibility.DOCUMENT);
    }
  }
}
```

gives this

```
[19-11-21 01:05:44:105 PST] Starting execution
[19-11-21 01:05:44:252 PST] PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties() [0.14 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:253 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getSheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:254 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getNumRows() [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:254 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getNumColumns() [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:255 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getCell([1, 1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:357 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.101 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:413 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([p 12 11]) [0.056 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:413 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getNumColumns() [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:414 PST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.createDeveloperMetadataFinder() [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:414 PST] SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataFinder.withKey([Updated]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:682 PST] SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataFinder.find() [0.267 seconds]
[19-11-21 01:05:44:836 PST] SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadata.setValue([p 12 11]) [0.153 seconds]
```

Any ideas on what makes these calls slow? Is there a way to optimize the code so that they run as fast as possible?

Comment: Have you  reviewed  "Best  practices" in the documentation?

Comment: Hey kajsa, I provided an answer which (hopefully) can help you. Let me know if you have any issue with it. Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97, Sadly that doesn't help as the example code is just an example and not what I actually do in my full file, as what I actually need to do is quite a few long functions. However, the issue I was trying to solve was that those precise calls take so long. I though maybe there was a formatting of some kind that could improve the speed. As it is, it seems that my only option is to use the API from an external call to the spreadsheet file, as all other options run into timeouts.

Comment: Hey @Kajsa, the idea of my answer was to convey that issuing several external calls (by use of built-in classes, extended services & urlfetchapp calls) can severely impact your performance (as they generally run sequentially, in a blocking fashion). May I ask, what do you mean by your last sentence "As it is, it seems that my only option is to use the API from an external call to the spreadsheet file, as all other options run into timeouts"? Cheers

Comment: What I meant is that running functions inside the google script environment runs into timeout errors due to the execution taking over 30 seconds. What I will do instead is to connect to the sheet from an external server, using python and the gspread package, to then request data through this connection. This, so far, runs much smoother as well as gives me a much more powerful set of tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Kajsa, I think I understood your question now. Kindly check my updated answer - I think you may be able to overcome this limitations if you change your trigger to an installable trigger...

Answer (score 0):

In your nested for-loops, you are issuing requests to `getCell()`, `getValue()`, and `setValue()`. That results in many remote requests to the Spreadsheets API, which slows down your script.

In order to greatly improve your script's performance, you can obtain all the data on the sheet with one single call (`getValues()`), apply the operations you please on it, and afterwards set it back to your sheet using yet another one single call (`setValues()`).

Also, I suggest that you take the "metadata" operations out of the loop, as it only seems to matter for the last value of `new_val`. Your final code after these modifications could look like:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  timetest(e)
}

function timetest(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var new_val;
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    for (var j=0; j<row.length; j++) {
      var value = row[j];
      new_val = value + ' ' + (i+1) + (j+1);
      row[j] = new_val;
    }
  }

  range.setValues(data);

  if (data.length > 0 && data[0].length > 0) {
    var metadata = sheet.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey("Updated").find()
    if (metadata.length > 0){
      metadata[0].setValue(new_val)
    } else {
      sheet.addDeveloperMetadata("Updated", new_val, SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataVisibility.DOCUMENT);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I suggest you check out [Best practices using Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

### Quotas

- The execution limit for simple triggers is of 30 seconds.
- When "installing" your onEdit trigger, that execution limit increases to the level of a "normal" script runtime, that is, 6 minutes for Consumer, G Suite Free and G Suite Basic/Gov and 30mins for Early Access and G Suite Business/Enterprise/Education.
- The daily allowed total trigger runtime is of 90 minutes per Consumer accounts, 3h for G Suite free edition accounts, and 6h for the higher-level accounts.

#### References

- [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)